# get youtube video id from video list

Tags: android, webview, youtube

**i m about to make youtube video downloader app but don't get to integrate youtube video list so below is testing code to get started with**

```
 webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.youtube.com");
```

> above code simply load youtube site to a webview .. now i want to get id or link  of clicked video

**or**

> is there any other way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read link from webview loading and parse the link

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
        {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

                //Parse Link
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
               //Parse Link
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onLoadResource(view, url);
            }
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                //Parse Link

                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            }
        });
```

Comment: hi did you manage to get it to work?
for some reason when im on youtube search page and clicking on a video none of  functions in the accepted answer is being called.